# Поиск в заданном диапазоне по буквам

Tags: c++

Есть так называемый "Телефонный справочник". Нужно выбрать тех абонентов, которые имеют имя в заданном диапазоне. То есть нужно ввести начало диапазона и конец и сравнить с ними первую букву имени. Если она находится посередине диапазона то вывести.
Не получается пройти по массиву и каждый цикло фор выводит первого абонента. Help

```
const int N = 20;

struct information
{
    char name[10];
    char location[20];
    long int number;
};

information directory[N] =
{
    {"Natasha", "Ciolkovskogo 25", 2652258},
    {"Maxsim", "Marta 126", 2523300},
    {"Alexei", "Geologisheskaia 15", 2311234},
    {"Victor", "Aviacionnaia 9", 2356577},
    {"Ksenia", "Lenina 2", 2001244},
    {"Ekaterina", "Belinskogo 49", 2230085},
    {"Elena", "Komandirov 2", 2260123},
    {"Vladimir", "Serafima 22", 2956565},
    {"Mihail", "Dekabristov 63", 2335544},
    {"Sasha", "Lyksemburg 50", 2102035},

    {"Masha", "Shatrova 77", 2667898},
    {"Boris", "Marta 16", 2523300},
    {"Chris", "Geologisheskaia 25", 2311234},
    {"Dariya", "Aviacionnaia 19", 2356577},
    {"Georgii", "Lenina 12", 2001244},
    {"Nikol'", "Belinskogo 49", 2230085},
    {"Olga", "Komandirov 2", 2260123},
    {"Petr", "Serafima 22", 2956565},
    {"Tatiana", "Dekabristov 63", 2335544},
    {"Fedor", "Lyksemburg 50", 2102035}
};
void FindName()
{
    char start;
    char end;
    bool found = false;
    std::cout << "\nVvedite nachalo diapazona dlia search: ";
    std::cin >> start;
    std::cout << "\nVvedite konec diapazona dlia search: ";
    std::cin >> end;
    std::cout << "\n  Name                 Address                        Telephone            \n"
              << " ==========================================================================\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (directory[IndexArray[i]].name[j] >= start && directory[IndexArray[i]].name[j] <= end)
            {
                std::cout << directory[IndexArray[i]].name << "\t\t\t" << directory[IndexArray[i]].location << "\t\t\t" << directory[IndexArray[i]].number << "\n";
                found = true;
            }
        }
        
    }
    if (found == false)
    {
        std::cout << "\nZapisi ne naideno!\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вы сравниваете все 10 букв имени, если сами пишете что нужна только первая..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сравнивайте так:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  {
      //name[0] - первая буква имени
      if (directory[i].name[0] >= start && directory[i].name[0] <= end)
      {
        std::cout << directory[i].name << "\t\t\t" << directory[i].location << "\t\t\t" << directory[i].number << "\n";
        found = true;
      }
  }
```